# How to get the top 5 elements with the highest occurrence(mode) in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to get the top 5 elements with the highest occurrence(mode) in a JavaScript array. I found a snippet of how to get the element with the highest but not for the top 5 or top 10.

Here is the code snippet for getting the highest occurrence below:

```
if(!Object.values) Object.values = function(ob){
var arr = [];
for(var k in ob) 
    if(ob.hasOwnProperty(k))
        arr.push(ob[k]);
return arr;
};

function multiMode(arr){
var map = arr.reduce(function(map, item){
    if(!(item in map)) map[item] = 0;
    return map[item]++, map;
}, {});
var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(map)),
    arr2 = [];
Object.keys(map).forEach(function(k){
    if(map[k] === max) arr2.push(k);  
});
return arr2;
}

console.log(multiMode(['pear', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple','apple']));


//Returns apple
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, build a map of key => count entries

```
let counts = arr.reduce((map, fruit) => {
    map[fruit] = (map[fruit] || 0) + 1;
    return map;
}, {});
```

Then create a sorted array from the keys

```
let sorted = Object.keys(counts).sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a]);
```

Then take the first 5

```
let top5 = sorted.slice(0, 5);
```

---

Legacy version if required

```
var counts = arr.reduce(function(map, fruit) {
    map[fruit] = (map[fruit] || 0) + 1;
    return map;
}, {});

var sorted = Object.keys(counts).sort(function(a, b) {
    return counts[b] - counts[a];
});

var top5 = sorted.slice(0, 5);
```

Comment: Easy on the ES6. Judging by the need for a polyfill for `Object.values`, I think this is client-side.

Comment: Sub `let` for `var` and `(arg1, arg2, ...) => ` for `function(arg1, arg2, ...)`. There's nothing else modern in here

Comment: @4castle even if it is client-side, there's pretty good browser support already. Works fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Phil can you create a JSBin Example for the code please? Thanks

Comment: @SteveW why? I'd just be directly copying the code in my answer

Comment: Thanks @Phil, it works, sorry was confusing the legacy and ES6 blocks

Answer (score 0):

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/sofobi/2/edit?js,console)

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,6,6,6,7,5];

// make map:
var m = a.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[b] = ++a[b] || 1;
  return a;
}, {});

// loop through object, get array of keys/values:
var arr = [];
for (var key in m) {
  arr.push([key, m[key]]);
}
// sort array by values:
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
});
// slice and map over 5 highest and return value:
console.log(arr.slice(-5).map(function(e) {
  return e[0];
}));
```

Comment: Why write your own `Object.keys()`?